# Give warning before getting logged off

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I would like to have a pop-up alert (warning) message that would be given 1 minute before the page redirects and logs off. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```js
(function() {
  var idleDurationSecs = 10 * 60;
  var redirectUrl = 'logout.asp'; // Redirect idle users to this URL
  var idleTimeout;

  var resetIdleTimeout = function() {
    if (idleTimeout) clearTimeout(idleTimeout);

    idleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      location.href = redirectUrl
    }, idleDurationSecs * 1000);
  };

  resetIdleTimeout();

  ['click', 'touchstart', 'mousemove'].forEach(function(evt) {
    document.addEventListener(evt, resetIdleTimeout, false)
  });
})();
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I guess you can create another timeout with `(idleDurationSecs - 60) * 1000` duration and set/reset it as you do now (inside `resetIdleTimeout`). In its callback you can show your alert.

Comment: @Walk Like this:                 resetIdleTimeout();
                                          (idleDurationSecs - 60) * 1000;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something with a little more quality, here is a code snippet of what I'd do. Ignore the CSS, I was just bored and made it look pretty. Pay attention to the code and the HTML.

```js
var n = 600; // 10 minutes

function countDown(){
var tm = setInterval(internalFunc,1000);
internalFunc();
       function internalFunc(){
         n--;
         if(n == 0){
            clearInterval(tm);
         }
          console.log(n);
          document.getElementById('ElementIDhere123').innerHTML = n;
          var date = new Date(null);
          date.setSeconds(n); // specify value for SECONDS here
          var result = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
          document.getElementById('ElementIDhere123').innerHTML = result;
       }
};

countDown();
```

```css
#ElementIDhere123{
background:-webkit-radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at right center, rgb(0, 151, 126) 0%, rgb(23, 95, 104) 80%);
background:-o-radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at right center, rgb(0, 151, 126) 0%, rgb(23, 95, 104) 80%);
background:-moz-radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at right center, rgb(0, 151, 126) 0%, rgb(23, 95, 104) 80%);
background:radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at right center, rgb(0, 151, 126) 0%, rgb(23, 95, 104) 80%);
border-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius:50px;
-webkit-border-radius:50px;
color:#C2F5FF;
text-align:center;
width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ElementIDhere123">Timer Placeholder</div>
```

---

**Since you asked how to put the time into an alert notifying the user when they were logged off.**

```
function startTime(){
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var ampm = h >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM';
  hours = h % 12;
  hours = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'

  return [ h, m, ampm ].join(':')
}

    (function () {
    var idleDurationSecs = 10 * 1;
    var warnDurationSecs = 9 * 1;
    var redirectUrl = 'logout.asp';  // Redirect idle users to this URL
    var idleTimeout;

    var resetIdleTimeout = function () {
        if (idleTimeout) clearTimeout(idleTimeout);
        if (idleMsg) clearTimeout(idleMsg);

        idleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            alert('You were logged off at ' + startTime());
            location.href = redirectUrl
        }, idleDurationSecs * 1000);

        idleMsg = setTimeout(function () {
        alert("You will be logged out in 1 minute");
    }, (warnDurationSecs) * 1000);
    };

    resetIdleTimeout();

    ['click', 'touchstart', 'mousemove'].forEach(function (evt) {
        document.addEventListener(evt, resetIdleTimeout, false)
    });
})();
```

Comment: That's a good countdown, but I would only want the redirect for inactivity. ['click', 'touchstart', 'mousemove']. How does this address that issue?

Comment: Is that part of your code not working? (regarding reset of the inactive time) I didn't read that it wasn't working. The first bit of code is compatible with it. If you'd like I can mesh the two together so you have the timer in the alert.

Comment: The first code is working on redirect.  If you could incorporate the 2 together that would be great.

Comment: Turns out, the timer is frozen in an alert pop-up, it will not update in realtime. So it's going to be one or the other.

Comment: Understand about pop-up. One or the other meaning just redirect or redirect with pop-up? Or are you referring to using the div?

Comment: How would you add the current time of the message in the pop-up? Pop-up works good.

Comment: I can add it but it doesn't update, it just pops up over and over with the new time so we can't put the countdown in the alert. I'd just put "You have 1 minute left before you are auto-logged out due to inactivity".

Comment: I was meaning, not to put the countdown in the message, but just to put the current time of the alert.  This way a person will know when they were logged out or when they got the message.

Comment: I've added a function for you. This is just what you're looking for I think.

Comment: Thank you for that, however when I open the page the timer goes off.  Does it require a certain placement on the page?  The one minute warning goes off too. Want would be ideal is that the time is in the warning so the user knows when the log off happened.  Not a separate timer.

Comment: Updated, mixed this new function with yours. Removed the 9 minute warning. So, after 10 mins, they will get the alert. As soon as the click OK to acknowledge, the page will redirect. There is no way to redirect with the message still up or the message will not be seen or the redirect will not happen. This is as good as it gets.

Comment: I can't seem to get this code to work.  I tried header and body. Not a problem is it doesn't redirect until message is click OK.  Just like the other code.  The last code l liked but was wanting this alert to go off (with the current time of message) and then giving that minute to continue activity.

Comment: You have to call the function. startTime();
If you want to add that back in all you need to do is add a 2nd interval which I had in the very first code I posted.

Comment: Sorry, but this code isn't working at all like the other one was. Non-responsive.

Comment: Fortunately I've shown you every method to fix it :) Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help.  All I did was copy and paste code like the first one worked so well and this one doesn't. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think that there needs to be a warning, and if there is, a simple alert is probably not sufficient. A div with a countdown would be best.

However, if you are set on using an alert then just use a second timeout.

```
var idleTimeout, warningTimeout;

var resetIdleTimeout = function () {
    clearTimeout(idleTimeout);
    clearTimeout(warningTimeout);

    warningTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        alert("You will be logged out in 1 minute");
    }, (idleDurationSecs-60) * 1000);

    idleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = redirectUrl
    }, idleDurationSecs * 1000);
};
```

Comment: Actually, I think that is a pretty good idea - not sure I know how to do that. Appreciate your assistance.